# how to send hexadecimal value in java to RS232 Serial port

Tags: java, binary, serial-port, byte, twos-complement

I need to send some commands to my microcontroller.
Iam using the RXTX library. I can connect to my microcontroller but i have problems to convert my commands to right bytes.

example:
i want to send 0x80 hex value.

if i convert 128 integer (0x80) to bytes

```
   byte a = (byte) 128;
```

i get  `-128`

the range from java bytes is `-128 - 127`

but i need to send 128 as a command. How can i convert it?

also i do have other commands to send.

```
80
20 F2 40 F8 3F 
FA 21 40
```

one of them is 40 bits.

I write to the outputstream, that can accept `byte[]` or `int`.

```
...
  static OutputStream out;
out.write(byte[]);
out.write(int); 
..
```

But int is out of range with 40bit. How can i parse a 40bit Integer to a byte?

[This Question helped me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/140131/convert-a-string-representation-of-a-hex-dump-to-a-byte-array-using-java)

Answer (score 1):

0x80 is still 0x80 regardless of what Java's signed-byte type system shows it as.

Just send it.

Comment: hm okay. My microcontroller is not responding to my commands, i thought maybe this is the problem :S

Answer (score 1):

I have used RXTX liberary a long back i don't think so it matters. just send string.getBytes()

Comment: i dont want to send the byte representation of the string

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
Byte.parseByte("a", 16);
```

but this will work only for values up to 127, values higher then that will need to cast to byte, due to signed/unsigned issues so i recommend to transfer it to an int and then cast it to byte

```
(byte) (Integer.parseInt("ef",16) & 0xff);
```

Comment: byte c =(byte) (Integer.parseInt("128",16) & 0xff);  give me 40 as output

Comment: You should pass hexadecimal value. 80